# Is this a normal behavior for *Flycheck error message*’s display?

Tags: flycheck, message

The following is an example of how my flycheck errors show up on emacs:

```
Method name &quot;createQATask&quot; doesn&#x27;t conform to 
&#x27;[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$&#x27; pattern [invalid-name]
```

Here are the checkers I’m running (checked through `C-c ! v`):

```
Syntax checkers for buffer __manifest__.py in python-mode:

First checker to run:

  python-flake8
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /usr/bin/python3
    - configuration file: Not found
    - `flake8' module:    Found at "/home/devdesk4/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flake8/__init__.py"
    - next checkers:      python-pylint, python-mypy

Checkers that may run as part of the first checker's chain:

  python-pylint
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /usr/bin/python3
    - configuration file: Found at "/home/devdesk4/.pylintrc"
    - `pylint' module:    Found at "/home/devdesk4/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py"
    - next checkers:      python-mypy

Checkers that could run if selected:

  python-pycompile  select
    - may enable:    yes
    - executable:    Found at /usr/bin/python3
    - next checkers: python-mypy
```

I’ve tried disabling `python-pylint`’s configuration file, but the behavior still remains. I’ve also tried a minimal `.emacs` configuration which only contained the following:

```
(setq package-archives                                                                                                                                                        
      '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")                                                                                                                             
        ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")                                                                                                                 
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")                                                                                                                      
        ("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/")))

(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init
  (global-flycheck-mode t))
```

Are those symbols (`&quot;`, `&#x27;`) not being displayed properly, or is this some sort of default flycheck configuration that I can override?

**April 25, 2020 Update (Possible Solution)**

Weirdly, I executed `pip install --upgrade pylint` just to check if I really had the latest version of `pylint`, and it upgraded from `2.3.0` to `2.4.4`, and that fixed the issue.

However, this solution conflicts with using https://pypi.org/project/pylint-odoo/, because it reverts me back to version `2.3.0` which has those html-escape sequences.

**Same-day update**

It’s [confirmed](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1746#issuecomment-619369897) to be an upstream bug in Pylint.

Comment: looks like the linter you're using is outputting to an html environment. change your linter's config to just output plain text.

Comment: I haven’t had any luck with configuring how the linter outputs stuff, mainly because I couldn't find the option to do that. 

However, I’ve tried running `C-c ! v` to check which linters/checkers are reading their respective configuration files from my home directory, then proceeded to disable them. There’s no change at all with how the symbols are being displayed.

Comment: maybe update your question with the linters you're using and what you're trying to lint.

Comment: @nega I agree, edited!